TA-lib installation conflicts with Conda
Despite I've already tried some of the workarounds that I found on Stack Overflow, I'm still not able to install TA-Lib in my conda enviroment. It seems that a more recent Python version is required, notwithstanding that my Python version is already the most recent. Please see below.
(base) C:\Users\salva>conda activate UUSeRR

(UUSeRR) C:\Users\salva>mamba install TA-lib

Looking for: ['ta-lib']

conda-forge/win-64                                          Using cache
conda-forge/noarch                                          Using cache
warning  libmamba Could not parse mod/etag header
warning  libmamba Could not parse mod/etag header
warning  libmamba Could not parse mod/etag header
warning  libmamba Could not parse mod/etag header
warning  libmamba Could not parse mod/etag header
warning  libmamba Could not parse mod/etag header
pkgs/main/win-64                                              No change
pkgs/main/noarch                                              No change
pkgs/r/win-64                                                 No change
pkgs/r/noarch                                                 No change
pkgs/msys2/win-64                                             No change
pkgs/msys2/noarch                                             No change

Pinned packages:
  - python 3.11.*


warning  libmamba Problem type not implemented SOLVER_RULE_STRICT_REPO_PRIORITY
warning  libmamba Problem type not implemented SOLVER_RULE_STRICT_REPO_PRIORITY
warning  libmamba Problem type not implemented SOLVER_RULE_STRICT_REPO_PRIORITY
warning  libmamba Problem type not implemented SOLVER_RULE_STRICT_REPO_PRIORITY
warning  libmamba Problem type not implemented SOLVER_RULE_STRICT_REPO_PRIORITY

warning  libmamba Added empty dependency for problem type SOLVER_RULE_UPDATE
Could not solve for environment specs
The following packages are incompatible
└─ ta-lib is installable with the potential options
   ├─ ta-lib [0.4.18|0.4.19] would require
   │  └─ python >=3.6,<3.7.0a0 , which can be installed;
   ├─ ta-lib [0.4.18|0.4.19] would require
   │  └─ python >=3.7,<3.8.0a0 , which can be installed;
   ├─ ta-lib [0.4.18|0.4.19] would require
   │  └─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 , which can be installed;
   ├─ ta-lib 0.4.19 would require
   │  └─ python >=3.10,<3.11.0a0 , which can be installed;
   └─ ta-lib 0.4.19 would require
      └─ python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0 , which can be installed.

(UUSeRR) C:\Users\salva>python --version
Python 3.11.9

(UUSeRR) C:\Users\salva>


This should now be resolved since the v0.4.32 PR was merged.

Previous Response
The ta-lib feedstock appeared to have fallen behind in maintenance. Neither the Python 3.11 nor 3.12 migration PRs had passed at time of the question. Thus, the solver could not install a version of TA-lib in the environment because there was no version available for Python 3.11. Moreover, the Conda solver will not change Python versions (beyond patches) in place without explicitly being told to do so.
Instead, create a new environment with Python 3.10 and install it there.
conda create -n foo python=3.10 ta-lib

Alternatively, one could send a PR to the Conda Forge feedstock to get it updated.
